# HP Thunderbolt Dock G2 won't go to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, thunderbolt

I am using a Thunderbolt Dock G2 with my Lenovo T480 under Windows 10. Annoyingly the dock won't go to sleep when the laptop is switched off or in stand-by. All USB peripherials connected on the dock will be thus powered through the night and the G2 fan is spinning. Only when I disconnect the laptop from the dock will the dock go to sleep.

What I have tried:

- Device Manager Settings for all USB Hubs and Thunderbolt Controllers has ticked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
- Setting USB charging to off in the BIOS both on Battery and when on Power
- Updating to the latest Dock firmware (1.0.71.1 Rev.B, Dec 15, 2022)
- Updating Thunderbolt controller driver (1.41.1229.0) and firmware (20.22.05.30-N24TF23W)

Is there any setting which could enable the dock to go to sleep or at least put the USB devices to sleep?

Comment: Note that there exist many posts about this dock not waking up from sleep. Apparently the problem goes both ways.

Comment: I never had this issue.